# Compiling cuda in VS2012: fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file, no such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-2012, cuda

I've installed Visual Studio 2012 and the CUDA 6.0 toolkit. I can start a new project and select the CUDA 6.0 Runtime, but when I try to compile, it apparently can't find the object file.

This is the output for the sample code that comes when creating a CUDA project, although I get the same problem even if it's just a normal C program without any CUDA syntax.

Here is the full output I get when building kernel.cu:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Temp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 08/06/2014 13:14:40.
1>PrepareForBuild:
1>  Creating directory "d:\my documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Temp\Debug\".
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Creating "Debug\Temp.unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>CudaBuild:
1>  Compiling CUDA source file kernel.cu...
1>  
1>  D:\Programming>"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "D:\Programs\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj "d:\my documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Temp\Temp\kernel.cu" 
1>nvcc : warning : The 'compute_10' and 'sm_10' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release.
1>  kernel.cu
1>C:\Users\Mort\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxft_00001d3c_00000000-20_kernel.ii : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: 'Debug/kernel.cu.obj': No such file or directory
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 6.0.targets(597,9): error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_10,code=\"sm_10,compute_10\" --use-local-env --cl-version 2012 -ccbin "D:\Programs\VC\bin"  -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v6.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir Debug -maxrregcount=0  --machine 32 --compile -cudart static  -g   -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi /RTC1 /MDd  " -o Debug\kernel.cu.obj "d:\my documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Temp\Temp\kernel.cu"" exited with code 1.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:03.36
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm running Win7 64 bit and VS 2012 Ultimate.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you doublecheck the path where nvcc is compiling your obj file? There might be a mismatch between the project path and nvcc's path ("D:\Programming")

Comment: I have no idea where nvcc would have gotten D:\Programming from, it's an old directory I used years ago; I just installed VS and Cuda a couple of days back and never pointed them at that directory, so something old must've remained stuck in there somewhere. Any chance you could let me know how to find/change the nvcc compile path?

Comment: Okay, so I searched the registry for D:\Programming and found some keys I'd set, I think to have command prompt default to that directory. I deleted those keys and now everything compiles fine. Thanks for pointing that out, would not have thought to look for that otherwise.

Comment: Glad I helped, I'll make this an answer so other people might benefit from it.

Comment: @user3511582 which directory do you set the command prompt default to? I previous set it to D:\ and now facing the same issue. I set it default to C drive but still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm making this an answer since it solved your problem: there seems to be a mismatch between NVCC's path (`D:\Programming`) and your project's path.

You might end up compiling stuff in the wrong directory and then failing to find the temporaries created by the previous phase. Make sure to fix those paths and the compilation should proceed just fine since everything else matches (i.e. bitness/include paths)